# Bootstrap 4 beta with react-slingshot

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-slingshot

I'm really new with webpack and react, I'm trying to add bootstrap 4-beta on the react-slingshot.

I'm looking for the proper way to do it.
I seen bootstrap-loader but I have some trouble to include it on the webpack ( No error but no styles added )

Answer (score 0):

It would be more useful if you add your Webpack file here. I do not use full bootstrap in my projects, but maybe you can consider using an alternative named [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)

React-Bootstrap has many components that you can use and it has the same look and feel as twitter bootstrap.